# How to create nested components which should be draggable inside there parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the start there will be a button `AddParent` on the top and nothing else. 
`AddParent` button  will add a parent Draggable to this component i.e every time the user clicks the AddParent button, a parent draggable should envelope the draggable component. Keep in mind that each level of component should in itself be draggable inside its parents’ window i.e. each of the title bars can be used to move around the respective component inside its parents’ blank box


Something like this (after 3 clicks of AddParent, there are 3 parents for the initial child) ->
(You don’t need to actually color the blank areas, it is just for ease of explanation...they can be white)
[image after 3 clicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J70wB.jpg)
you can see this short [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-iIEKaypmNUQUdlQkOlytWjjFo1GO1K/view) to understand the objective.

I am only able to code draggable part even that that is not working perfectly.

```
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
import "./create.css";

function CreateComp() {

    const createParentComp = () =>{

    }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={createParentComp}>Add Parent</button>
      <section className="container">
        <Draggable handle=".handle" bounds='parent'>
            <div style={{width: '400px', height:'400px'}}>
                <p className="handle">Drage here</p>
                <Draggable handle=".handle" bounds='parent'>
                <div style={{width: '200px', height:'200px'}}>
                <p className="handle">Drag here</p>
            </div>
                </Draggable>
            </div>
            
        </Draggable>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreateComp;
```

Please help me to achive my goal.

Edit: This is my updated code - [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-smoke-erw0tt?file=/src/App.js), it is working but not able to stop event bubbling, when I drag child components then its parent components are also getting dragged.